# Get a char from the mouse position inside HTML <pre> tag

Tags: javascript, html, mouse

I'm using the `<pre>` tag to display an ASCII board for a little two-dimensional game.
This `<pre>` contains some simple textnodes and `<span>`s (which are useful to set a color for certains chars).

I need interactions with the mouse, so I'd like to deduce a **char position** (or offset) (a (x, y) couple) inside this `<pre>` zone regarding my current mouse coordinates (that I already know and which are in pixels).

(x, y) => (xChar, yChar)

Any ideas to get this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`clientX`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp) and [`clientY`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clienty.asp) properties to achieve this, like so:

```html
<style>
pre
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>Click in the pre element below to get the x (horizontal) and y (vertical) coordinates of the mouse pointer, when it is clicked.</p>

<p id="demo">Click inside!</p>
<pre onclick="showCoords(event)">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
</pre>

<script>
function showCoords(event) {
    var cX = Math.round(event.clientX/10);
    var cY = Math.round((event.clientY-50)/30);
    //var cY = event.clientY;
    var coords1 = "X: " + cX + ", Y: " + cY;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords1
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that my question is not clear enough. I need to get the offset of the char that my mouse is over.

Comment: @Guid Is this what you wanted? I did my best to approximate the grid of characters by dividing the X and Y values by arbitrary numbers. Run it in full-screen for much better consistency.